# Scaling features for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-structures, scikit-learn

I have a question about how to scale my dataset properly.

It consists of

1. A date which I currently store as seconds
2. A value that can be between 1 and 5
3. And about 240 bool values 1 or 0

So a row looks something like

```
[1514761200, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,  ......]
```

I tried to apply the `scikit StandardScaler` but it leads to some really weird values, some 0 stay 0 others are scaled to something like -1.736. And if i then apply inverse_transform on the data some bool values stay weird numbers.

I think the problem is the huge number in the date column, I'm not sure.

But if, what is a better way to handle dates or in general how do I handle 1/2 columns that just doesn't fit the rest of the data but are mandatory.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to scale categorical data? What is your problem? What is your intention of scaling?

Comment: what part of my dataset is categorical? I just want to achieve that the model treats every input column the same way I thought thats the purpose of scaling that you get rid of huge differences between the size of the input value.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Actually you can use scaling to get rid of the bias in features. This can be important in gradient optimization procedures. If most of your data is categorical maybe you should consider tree learning algorithms which get along with categorical data pretty well. Boolean is a special form of categorical. Are your values between 1 and 5 integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaling is in most cases applied to each feature seperately, and that's what StandardScaler is doing. Therefore it is totally natural that some 0s stay zero while others are transformed. Look at the following code

```
int_mat = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]])
```

Output

```
array([[0, 0],
   [0, 1],
   [0, 2]])
```

Now we do scaling

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ssc = StandardScaler()
int_scaled = ssc.fit_transform(int_mat)
inverse_scaling = ssc.inverse_transform(int_scaled)
```

int_scaled

```
array([[ 0.        , -1.22474487],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.22474487]])
```

as you see, the first feature (first column) stays the same because it has already zero mean.

Inverse transformation results in the original matrix

inverse_scaling

```
array([[0.00000000e+00, 1.11022302e-16],
       [0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: that made things a lot more clear, I thought scaling happens in relation to the other columns but it now makes much more sense, thanks

Comment: But be careful when scaling categorical data! You should have a good reason for this or use algorithms which work with metrics that take care of categorical data