# Normalizations in sklearn and their differences

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I have read many articles suggested this formula

```
N = (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

for normalization

but when i dig into the normalizor of sklearn somewhere i found they are using this formula

```
x / np.linalg.norm(x)
```

As the later use l2-norm by default. Which one  should I use? Why is there a difference in between both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different normalization techniques and sklearn provides for many of them. Please note that we are looking at 1d arrays here. For a matrix these operations are applied to each **column** (have a look at this post for an in depth example [Scaling features for machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511581/9534390)) Let's go through some of them:

1. Scikit-learn's `MinMaxScaler` performs `(x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))` This scales your array in such a way that you only have values between 0 and 1. Can be useful if you want to apṕly some transformation afterwards where no negative values are allowed (e.g. a log-transform or in scaling RGB pixels like done in some MNIST examples)
2. scikit-learns `StandardScaler` performs `(x-x.mean())/x.std()` which centers the array around zero and scales by the variance of the features. This is a standard transformation and is appicable in many situations but keep in mind that you will get negative values. This is especially useful when you have gaussian sampled data which is not centered around 0 and/or does not have a unit variance.
3. Scikit-learn's `Normalizer` performs `x / np.linalg.norm(x)`. This sets the length of your array/vector to 1. Might come in handy if you want to do some linear algebra stuff like if you want to implement the Gram-Schmidt Algorithm.
4. Scikit-learn's `RobustScaler` can be used to scale data with outliers. Mean and standard deviation are not robust to outliers therefore this scaler uses the median and scales the data to quantile ranges.
5. There are other non-linear transformations like `QuantileTransformer` that scales be quantile ranges and `PowerTransformer` that maps any distribution to a distribution similar to a Gaussian distribution.

And there are many other normalizations used in machine learning and there vast amount can be confusing. The idea behind normalizing data in ML is usually that you want dont want your model to treat one feature differently than others simply because it has a higher mean or a larger variance. For most standard cases I use `MinMaxScaler` or `StandardScaler` depending on whether scaling according to the variance seems important to me.

Answer (score 1):

np.ling.norm is given by:

`np.linalg.norm(x) = sqrt((sum_i_j(abs(x_i_j)))^2)`

so lets assume you have:

```
X= (1  2
    0  -1)
```

then with this you would have:

```
np.linalg.norm(x)= sqr((1+2+0+1)^2)= sqr(16)=4
X = (0.25 0.5
     0    -0.25)
```

with the other approach you would have:

```
min(x)= -1
max(x)= 2
max(x)-min(x)=3
X = (0.66 1
     0.33 0)
```

So the min(x)/max(x) is also called MinMaxScaler, there all the values are always between 0-1, the other approaches normalizes your values , but you can still have negativ values. Depending on your next steps you need to decide which one to use.

Comment: [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-can-I-log-transform-a-series-with-both-positive-and-negative-values) are some tips for **negative values** -- e.g. in log transformormation

Answer (score 1):

[Based on the API description](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

Scikit-learn normalizer scales input vectors individually to a unit norm (vector length).

That is why it uses the L2 regularizer (you can also use L1 as well, as explained in the API)

I think you are looking for a scaler instead of a normalizer by your description. Please find the Min-Max scaler in this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).

Also, you can consider a [standard scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) that normalizes value by removing its mean and scales to its standard deviation.